# calling @PostConstruct on super bean AND extending bean

Tags: jsf, postconstruct

I have a BaseBean with a @PostConstruct, and a bean extending it on which i would like to call another @PostConstruct. I have read several places where it said it was possible, however, it seems the @postConstruct on the extending class is called first (if the second is called at all). I then get a NPE on "context" because I'm assuming the super bean's PostConstruct has already been called.

Is this do-able? If so what am I doing wrong?

Base bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BaseBean {
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{contextBean}")
  private ContextBean contextBean;
  Context context;
@PostConstruct
public void setupContext() {
    context = getContextBean().getContext();
}
```

Extending bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SmartBoxSearchBean extends BaseBean {
@PostConstruct
public void setUp() {
    jsonHelper = context.get(SmartBoxJsonHelper.class);
}
```

Thanks,
Yotam.

Comment: @YotamSeon I have a very similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29787068/330457). Did you concluded that the accepted suggestion is the only solution you could?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `@PostConstruct` of the superclass of a backing bean is not called at all when the managed bean is constructed. It's only called when a **completely separate** managed bean instance of that superclass is been constructed by e.g. using `#{baseBean}` in EL in your case. You effectively end up with two entirely separate instances `#{baseBean}` and `#{smartBoxSearchBean}` wherein the class' own `@PostConstruct` method is invoked independently on the managed bean class itself.

This design is somewhat strange. A superclass of a backing bean is normally not to be used as a managed bean at all.

I suggest to revise your approach as follows:

```
public abstract class BaseBean {

    @ManagedProperty("#{contextBean}")
    private ContextBean contextBean;

    public Context getContext() {
        return contextBean.getContext();
    }

}
```

and

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SmartBoxSearchBean extends BaseBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void setUp() {
        jsonHelper = getContext().get(SmartBoxJsonHelper.class);
    }

}
```

Or maybe this, if you don't need `ContextBean` for other purposes at all

```
public abstract class BaseBean {

    @ManagedProperty("#{contextBean.context}")
    private Context context;

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

}
```

Note that `@ManagedProperty` works just fine when declared in a superclass this way.

---

**Update**: depending on the functional requirements, you can also decouple the beans and just inject the `#{baseBean}` in the `{smartBoxSearchBean}`.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BaseBean {

    @ManagedProperty("#{contextBean}")
    private ContextBean contextBean;
    private Context context;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        context = contextBean.getContext();
    }

}
```

and

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SmartBoxSearchBean {

    @ManagedProperty("#{baseBean}")
    private BaseBean baseBean; 

    @PostConstruct
    public void setUp() {
        jsonHelper = baseBean.getContext().get(SmartBoxJsonHelper.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC for the super quick answer. Your solution would work, except for one issue - In the BaseBean's PostConstruct i also initialize other members, that the extending beans use...