# @PostConstruct of abstract ancestors are not invoked

Tags: java, unit-testing, jersey, jax-rs, cdi

I'm writing a JAX-RS library (not an application).

I have:

```java
abstract class A {

    @PostConstruct
    private void constructed_a() {} // not invoked

    @Inject
    private Some some;
}


public abstract class B extends A {

    @PostConstruct
    private void constructed_b() {} // not invoked
}
```

And test class:

```
@Path("c")
public class C extends B {

    @PostConstrct
    private void constructed_c() {} // invoked
}
```

I'm testing with jersey test framework v2.17

I found that only `constructed_c()` is invoked and those method defined in ancestors are not invoked. Note that the field(`some`) declared with `@Inject` in class `A` is properly injected.

Is this normal? What should I do?

---

**Conclusion**

I tested with embedded-glassfish and found that, as Antonin Stefanutti pointed, those callback methods invoked in order as expected.

```
constructed_a()
constructed_b()
constructed_c()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to section *Invocation Order of Interceptors Declared on the Target Class* of the [JSR 318 - Interceptors 1.2](https://java.net/downloads/interceptors-spec/interceptor-1-2-mrel.pdf) specification:

> Interceptor methods declared on the target class or its superclasses
>   are invoked in the following order:
>
> - If a target class has superclasses, any interceptor methods defined on those superclasses are invoked, most general superclass first.
> - The interceptor method, if any, on the target class itself is invoked.
>
> If an interceptor method is overridden by another method (regardless
>   of whether that method is itself an interceptor method), it will not
>   be invoked.

That means that when writing a library / framework, it is possible to achieve extensibility while using the `@PostConstruct` lifecyle callback both in the parent class and the child class.

That mechanism is used in the Camel CDI extension that declares a default Camel context with a `@PostConstruct` lifecycle callback in https://github.com/astefanutti/camel-cdi/blob/b6f52d91b247e36eefb6f3ecde61016d681d3535/impl/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/cdi/CdiCamelContext.java#L37

And that can be extended by users like in https://github.com/astefanutti/camel-cdi/blob/b6f52d91b247e36eefb6f3ecde61016d681d3535/envs/se/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/cdi/se/bean/CustomLifecycleCamelContext.java#L37 that declares its own `@PostConstruct` lifecycle callback.

Both being called by the container following the specified order.

That means that your approach is correct from the design standpoint. However, as Jersey dependency injection is based on HK2 and not CDI and relies on bridges like `jersey-gf-cdi` there might be an issue at that level.

Comment: Question: I see `CustomLifecycleCamelContext` explicitly overrides the `postConstruct()` without `super.postConstruct()`? According the spec you quote, The code defined in `CdiCamelContext`'s `postConstruct()` should not be executed. Should it?

Comment: The `postConstruct()` method in the parent class is *packaged-private* (default visibility). Hence it is not accessible from the child class and is not considered as overriden.

Comment: My short journey ended [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29818855/330457). Thank you @AntoninStefanutti

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not following. I admit, I haven't run Jin Kwon's example, but based on what he posted, the `@PostConstruct` functions are not overriden via having different method names. Are we saying that the reason that the `@PostConstruct` parent functions weren't called had nothing to do with `@PostConstruct` itself? and the functions not being called had to do with the improper use of the Jersey framework?

Answer (score 2):

Annotations are not inherited. You must create a `@PostConstruct` annotated method for each sub-class.

To assist/remind the developer, you could require a `postConstruct()` method and hope the developer annotates it appropriately as suggested by its name:

```
public abstract class A {

    @PostConstruct // annotation here has no value except as a reminder
    public abstract void postConstruct();
```

Comment: But there are things must be happened in `A#constructed_a()`. You're suggesting make it overridable and subclasses must call `super.postConstruct()`?

Comment: @JinKwon yes. The container will only invoke the `@PostConstruct` annotated method of the class being instantiated (not the super class's annotated method)

Comment: It should also be noted that [Only one method can be annotated with this annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html). So I'm guessing that trickles down to matters of inheritance also. From what I've tested, if you get rid of C's PostConstruct, B's will be called

Comment: @peeskillet When I removed those two `abstract` from A and B. And `constructed_a()` is invoked only. Honestly I really don't understand.

Comment: @JinKwon The point I'm getting at is that only one annotated method will be called for the entire inheritence chain. The nearest one to the create type will be called. If C is the created type, and it has an annotated method, that method will get called. If you remove the annotation from C, then the next up the chain with the annotation will be called, B's. If you remove the annotation from B and C, then A's will be called